# AVAssetExportSession export takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession, avasset

My goal is to let user select video from photos and then let him to add labels over it.

Here is what I've got:

```
let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(url: selectedVideoURL)
let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: selectedVideoURL)
let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
let compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
let clipAudioTrack = audioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
do {
    try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration), of: clipAudioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform
} catch {
    print(error)
}
var videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize
if isVideoPortrait(asset: videoAsset) {
    videoSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.height, height: videoSize.width)
}
let parentLayer = CALayer()
let videoLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

// adding label
let helloLabelLayer = CATextLayer()
helloLabelLayer.string = "Hello"
helloLabelLayer.font = "Signika-Semibold" as CFTypeRef?
helloLabelLayer.fontSize = 30.0
helloLabelLayer.contentsScale = mainScreen.scale
helloLabelLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentNatural
helloLabelLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0)
parentLayer.addSublayer(helloLabelLayer)

// creating composition
let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
let layerInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)
instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
videoComp.instructions = [instruction]
if let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset640x480) {
    let filename = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("video.mov")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filename) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filename)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
assetExport.outputURL = url
assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp
print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
assetExport.exportAsynchronously {
    print(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
    library.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: url, completionBlock: {
        (url, error) in
        switch assetExport.status {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                p("failed \(assetExport.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                p("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
            default:
                p("complete")
                p(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filename) {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filename)
                    } catch {
                        p(error)
                    }
                }
                print("Exported")                                    
        }
    })
}
```

Implementation of `isVideoPortrait` function:

```
func isVideoPortrait(asset: AVAsset) -> Bool {
    var isPortrait = false
    let tracks = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if tracks.count > 0 {
        let videoTrack = tracks[0]
        let t = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        if t.a == 0 && t.b == 1.0 && t.c == -1.0 && t.d == 0 {
            isPortrait = true
        }
        if t.a == 0 && t.b == -1.0 && t.c == 1.0 && t.d == 0 {
            isPortrait = true
        }
        if t.a == 1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == 1.0 {
            isPortrait = false
        }
        if t.a == -1.0 && t.b == 0 && t.c == 0 && t.d == -1.0 {
            isPortrait = false
        }
    }
    return isPortrait
}
```

And the last function for `video composition layer instruction`:

```
func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
    let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
    instruction.setTransform(transform, at: kCMTimeZero)
    return instruction
}
```

The code works well, output video has label, but if I select 1 minute video, export takes 28 seconds.

I've search for it and tried to remove `layerInsctuction` transform, but no effect.

Tried to add:
`assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false`
no effect either.

Also, tried to set `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` for `AVAssetExportSession`, in this case video exports with 1 second but labels have gone.

Any help would be appreciated, because I'm in stuck. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are doing two time-consuming things: the export, and the copy into the photos album. Which one is taking a long time?

Comment: Also: when something takes a long time and you want to know why, use Instruments. Did you try that? What did it tell you?

Comment: @matt Basically, export takes a lot of time. Copying to photos album takes 1 second. I didn't used instruments yet, should I use "Activity Monitor", when I run Instruments, for this?

Comment: You should time profile.

Comment: @matt I've used Time Profile, run the app and perform all usual steps.
[Here](http://oi66.tinypic.com/whl2xk.jpg) is the output, but it's a bit complicated. Can you help what should I look for?

Comment: You need to keep opening the main thread (because it is the most time-consuming) and then keep opening whatever is most time-consuming until you come to _your_ code. You will then be able to see what's taking time, and you can even see a view of your code that marks each _line_ with how time-consuming it is. It's pretty fantastic! Watch WWDC 2016 session 418 for a good intro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to reduce the quality via the bit rate and resolution.

This is done through a dictionary applied to the videoSettings of the AssetExporter, for this to work I had to use a Framework called `SDAVAssetExportSession`

Then by changing the videoSettings I could play with the quality to get an optimal quality / speed.

```
    let compression = [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : 2097152(DESIRED_BITRATE),AVVideoProfileLevelKey : AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel]

    let videoSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : maxWidth, AVVideoHeightKey : maxHeight, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:compression]
```

This was the only way I could speed things up.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to halved the time.

Comment: I don't believe you have to use a framework for this (unless I'm missing something), you can get the presets out of ```AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: yourVideoAsset)``` and then pass them over to your ```AVAssetExportSession``` instantiation.

Comment: I believe these particular keys are not compatible with AVAssetExportSession, you have to use the lower down AVAssetWriter, which is what this drop in file does under the hood.

Comment: Has anybody found any solution to reduce time that exportAsynchronously takes to export a video/audio. It takes a lot of time for me to encode large audios of length 5:00 and above. I tried using AVAssetExportSession and SDAVAssetExportSession but both have same results. :(

Comment: @AliRaza It depends, are you recording a video/audio, then re-encoding it to reduce size,  or just trasncoding existing static files?

Comment: @SeanLintern I am recording audio which I believe is not being encoded as it records. When I click the done button, then It takes time to encode it which grows with the length of audio recorded.

Comment: @AliRaza then you need to change the recording quality using  SDAVAssetExportSession

Comment: @SeanLintern I already reduced it to the minimum. It improved encoding time but it still takes time. For this reason, I cannot save audio fully when phone rings because it has to take time for encoding.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly relevant to your question, but your code here is backwards:

```
assetExport.exportAsynchronously {
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
    library.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: url, completionBlock: {
        switch assetExport.status {
```

No no no. First you complete the asset export. Then you can copy again to somewhere else if that's what you want to do. So this needs to go like this:

```
assetExport.exportAsynchronously {
    switch assetExport.status {
    case .completed:
        let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
        library.writeVideoAtPath...
```

Other comments:

- ALAssetsLibrary is dead. This is not the way to copy into the user's photo library. Use Photo framework.
- Your original code is very odd, because there are a lot of other cases you are not testing for. You are just *assuming* that `default` means `.completed`. That's dangerous.

Comment: No worries. I'm sorry this is not a real answer; I'll probably have to delete it. :) But there was no way to say all that in a comment.